# The spectrum of the product $JA$ where $J=I_n\oplus (-I_n)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis, eigenvector

Let  $A$ be a real symmetric matrix in $M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$with $A^2=I_{2n}$. Suppose that  the Schur decomposition of $A$ is given by $A=\Lambda^t D \Lambda$. Let us consider  the following matrix.
$$J=I_n\oplus (-I_n)$$

Q. By the eigen values/eigenvectors of $A$, can we find/make some eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the product $JA$?

p.s. We denote $I_n$ by the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $-I_n$ is its negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original question:** *What information can be extracted  concerning the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the product $JA$?*

The matrix $JA$ is orthogonal,
$$JA(JA)^\top=JA^2J=J^2=I,$$
so its eigenvalues $\lambda_p$ are complex conjugate pairs $e^{\pm i\phi_p}$ on the unit circle. The eigenvectors are an orthonormal set.

Comment: Okay, that is true for any orthogonal symmetric matrix. The question is concerned with finding some eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $JA$ which are made/obtained somehow by the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $A$. I made some clarifications in the question.

Comment: the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ fully determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $JA$, but the algebraic relation for arbitrary $n$ is not simple, as you can see by considering small $n$.

Comment: also, please avoid changing a question after it has been answered, or at least keep the original formulation for the record.